# "MOVE" and "COPY" requests with Powershell's Invoke-RestMethod cmdlet?

Tags: rest, powershell-3.0

The Live Connect Representational State Transfer (REST) API draws on the HTTP verbs "MOVE" to move the location of a resource and "COPY" to copy a resource.

We can draw conveniently on Powershell's Invoke-RestMethod cmdlet for any kind of Live Connect request except for "MOVE" and "COPY" requests as these two methods are not supported, i.e. they are missing from the WebRequestMethod enumeration:

```
[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestMethod] | Get-Member -Static
```

Would there be ways to overcome this limitation of the Invoke-RestMethod cmdlet?

Currently, we draw on .Net's System.Net.WebRequest class to implement the missing methods.